# Estimate mass of fruit in a bag from only related totals?

Tags: regression, estimation

An instructor at my university posed a question like this (not for homework since the class is over and I wasn't in it). I can't figure out how to approach it.

The question concerns 2 bags each containing an assortment of different kinds of fruits:

The first bag contains the following randomly selected fruit:

```
+-------------+--------+---------+
| diameter cm | mass g | rotten? |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| 17.28       | 139.08 |       0 |
| 6.57        | 91.48  |       1 |
| 7.12        | 74.23  |       1 |
| 16.52       | 129.8  |       0 |
| 14.58       | 169.22 |       0 |
| 6.99        | 123.43 |       0 |
| 6.63        | 104.93 |       1 |
| 6.75        | 103.27 |       1 |
| 15.38       | 169.01 |       1 |
| 7.45        | 83.29  |       1 |
| 13.06       | 157.57 |       0 |
| 6.61        | 117.72 |       0 |
| 7.19        | 128.63 |       0 |
+-------------+--------+---------+
```

The second bag contains 6 randomly selected fruit from the same store as the first bag. The sum of their diameters is 64.2 cm and 4 are rotten.

**Give an estimate for the mass of the second bag.**

I can see that there appear to be two different kinds of fruit with normally distributed diameters and masses but I am lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Interesting question--but strange data: the specific gravities range from 0.78 down to 0.05.  Maybe somebody mistook the styrofoam decorations for real fruit? :-)

Comment: The question does not say what the fruit was made of. I guess that you can assume that the actual bags themselves are weightless as well.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: The thrust of my comment was that when analyzing such small amounts of messy data, we rely on knowledge of what the data mean. Since these numbers obviously do not describe any known kind of "fruit," we cannot appeal to such domain knowledge. (For instance, we have no basis whatsoever to suppose that any part of these data ought to be "normally distributed.") That makes it difficult or impossible to develop reasonable answers and can lead to controversy, because it limits the ways in which the performance of any approach can be assessed.

Comment: But styrofoam fruit can't rot. Perhaps the fruit are prolate spheroids, with "diameter" measured along the long axis. There seem to be at least two kinds of fruit: so, assuming specific gravities close to one, the smaller would be about the size and shape of a lemon; the larger about half a foot long & under 2 inches across. The difficulty with this idea is that it seems more natural to describe the shorter axis as the "diameter".

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by plotting the data and take a look at it. This is a very limited amount of data, so this is going to be somewhat *ad hoc* with plenty of assumptions.

```
rotten <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
rotten <- as.factor(rotten)
mass <- c(139.08, 
        91.48,
        74.23,
        129.8,
        169.22,
        123.43,
        104.93,
        103.27,
        169.01,
        83.29,
        157.57,
        117.72,
        128.63)
diam <- c(17.28,
        6.57,
        7.12,
        16.52,
        14.58,
        6.99,
        6.63,
        6.75,
        15.38,
        7.45,
        13.06,
        6.61,
        7.19)

plot(mass,diam,col=rotten,lwd=2)
title("Fruits")
```

So this is the data, red dots represent rotten fruits:

[image: fruits plotted]

You are correct in assuming that there seem to be two kinds of fruits. The assumptions I make are the following:

- The diameter splits the fruits into two groups
- Fruits with a diameter greater than 10 are in one group, others in the smaller group.
- There is only one rotten fruit in the big fruit group. Let's assume that the if a fruit is in the large group, then being rotten does not affect the weight. This is essential, since we only have one data point in that group.
- If the fruit is a small fruit, then being rotten affects the mass.
- Let's assume that the variables diam and mass are normally distributed.

Because it is given that the sum of the diameter is 64.2 cm, then it is most likely that two fruits are large and four are small. Now there are 3 cases for the weight. There is 2, 3 or 4 small fruits rotten, (*a large fruit being rotten does not affect the mass by assumption*). So now you can get bounds on your mass by calculating these values.

We can empirically estimate the probability for number of small fruits being rotten. We use the probabilities to weight our estimates of the mass, depending on the number of rotten fruits:

```
samps <- 100000
stored_vals <- matrix(0,samps,2)
for(i in 1:samps){
  numF <- 0 # Number of small rotten
  numR <- 0 # Total number of rotten
  # Pick 4 small fruits
  for(j in 1:4){
    if(runif(1) < (5/8)){ # Empirical proportion of small rotten
      numF <- numF + 1
      numR <- numR + 1
    } 
  }
  # Pick 2 large fruits
  for(j in 1:2){
    if(runif(1) < 1/5){# Empirical proportion of large rotten
      numR <- numR + 1
    }
  }
  stored_vals[i,] <- c(numF,numR)
}

# Pick out samples that had 4 rotten
fourRotten <- stored_vals[stored_vals[,2] == 4,1]
hist(fourRotten)

table(fourRotten)

# Proportions 
props <- table(fourRotten)/length(fourRotten)

massBig <- mean(mass[diam>10])
massSmRot <- mean(mass[diam<10 & rotten == 1])
massSmOk <- mean(mass[diam<10 & rotten == 0])

weights <- 2*massBig + c(2*massSmOk+2*massSmRot,1*massSmOk+3*massSmRot,4*massSmRot)

Est_Mass <- sum(props*weights)
```

Giving us a final estimate of **691.5183g**. I think you have to make most of the assumptions I have made to reach a conclusion, but I think it might be possible to do this in a smarter way. Also I sample empirically to get the probability of number of rotten small fruits, that is just laziness and can be done "analytically".

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  It seems to me that most of the assertions you call "assumptions" are really *conclusions* based on your exploratory analysis.  It would be valuable to analyze how your results depend on the accuracy of those conclusions.  Regardless, it's clear that such a small dataset cannot possibly support a result with seven significant figures!  It would be especially useful to supply some assessment of its likely error. It will be relatively large, which would be important to know.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment, I might add something more for estimating the variation later in the evening. The simplest thing to do would be to get error estimates for the mass of the three groups I use for the final calculation, and calculate prediction intervals based on that. But I see that OP has been inactive for a year, so I do not expect this answer to be accepted. I still think that this example is a nice "toy" problem to see how for you can get with so little data.

Comment: I am trying to suggest that you actually get much less information than suggested by your answer, because it depends on many data-derived conclusions that themselves are highly uncertain.

Comment: @whuber Yes that is entirely correct. But trying to estimate the error propagated by all the assumptions/conclusion I make is not very simple. I was also heavily influenced by the fact that the sum of the diameters of the fruits in the second bag is 64.2cm and that OP mentions that there might be two groups of fruits.

Comment: "Not very simple" is precisely what can make a situation interesting.  A simple question probably already has an answer somewhere on this site.

Comment: @whuber I'll think about this and take this as a challenge. I'll revisit this question later!

Comment: I look forward to reading what you come up with!

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following approach:

1. Generate all 6-tuples that satisfy the conditions on 4 rotten. They are ${6\choose 4}{7\choose 2}$.
2. Select from the generated tuples only those that satisfy the the condition on the diameter.
3. Calculate the average weight of the selected tuples (usual arithmetic average).

All this is manageable by a simple script.

Comment: Why should this approach work?  What assumptions does it make?  Have you tried it to see whether it can even produce an answer at all?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple approaches include, from simplest to complex,

1. 6(mean mass)
2. 6(mean volume)(mean density)
3. 4(mean rotten mass) + 2 (mean non-rotten mass)
4. 4((mean rotten volume) + 2(mean non-rotten volume))(mean density)
5. 4 (mean rotten volume)(mean rotten density) + 2(mean non-rotten volume)(mean non-rotten density)

.
.
.

combinatoric methods

The approaches are arranged in order of simplicity of calculating, not in order of any approach being better, or any good at all. Selection of which approach to use depends upon what characteristics of the population are known or assumed. For example, if the masses of fruits in the store population are normally distributed and independent of diameters and rot status, one could use the first, simplest approach without any advantages (or even disadvantages of sampling error of multiple variables) of using more complex approaches. If not independent identically distributed random variables, then a more complex choice depending upon known or assumed information about the population may be better.

Comment: Why are any of these any good?  What assumptions do they make?  How would one select one over the other?  (Are they also in order of ascending goodness in some sense?)